# Regual expression strange behavior

Tags: c++, regex, qt

```
QRegExp regexpsplineedit("[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\[\\]\\(\\)]{20}");
qlineedit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regexpsplineedit,this));
```

This work.
And this not :

```
if(clipboardtext.contains(QRegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\[\\]\\(\\)]{20}")))
```

But this yes :

```
if(clipboardtext.contains(QRegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\[\\]\\(\\)]")) && clipboardtext.length() <= 20)
```

Why this happens with same text for input?

Comment: In what way does something work?

Comment: @sln, in last `if` `.cntains` return `true` like with `qlineedit`but `.containts` in first `if` returns `false` and if i delete max length from regular expresion in first `if` he work properly and doesn't metter what text is in buffer.

Comment: How can `if(something)` be false, whereas `if(something && otherthing)` be true? Don't make sense.

Comment: @sln, sorry i made mistake at last if with this `{20}` but i describe sitiation in comment above. So the problem in `{20}` but why i can't understand.

Comment: Are you validating the length of the string is less than or equal to 20? Or that at least 1 char from that class exists _and_ the total length is less than or equal to 20? That is 2 separate validation steps. Otherwise, its just `^[chars]{1,20}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you validating the length of the string is less than or equal to 20? Or that at least 1 char from that class exists *and* the total length is less than or equal to 20? That is 2 separate validation steps. Otherwise, its just `^[chars]{1,20}$`
                    – sln